# Container inside ListView will expand even though it has height

Tags: flutter, dart

The following Container inside a ListView, won't have a height, even though I specified one. Instead it expands to the entire ListView's height

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 20,
            color: Colors.red)
        ])
                                    
    );
  }
}
```

According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html,

> If the widget has no child and no alignment, but a height, width, or
> constraints are provided, then the Container tries to be as small as
> possible given the combination of those constraints and the parent's
> constraints.

so shouldn't the Container be as small as possible, since it has constraints?

Comment: Is wrapping the listview itself in a container with specified height not an option? This would work but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Understanding Constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints)  in Flutter Docs.

The `constraints` given by the `ListView` to its `children` is too exactly fill the cross axis. Your `Container` cannot decide to have a size out of these `constraints`.

Remember, `constraints` go down, `sizes` go up.

---

You should position your `Containers` inside the `ListView`. In the following example, the first `Container` (Red) is not positioned, the second (Green) is `Centered` and the last (Blue) is `Aligned` on `topLeft`:

`Center` and`Align` widgets both will take maximum height and give flexibility to their child, your `Container`.

[image]

### Full source code:

```dart
import 'dart:math' show Random;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            Container(width: 100, height: 20, color: Colors.red),
            Center(
              child: Container(width: 100, height: 10, color: Colors.green),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Container(width: 100, height: 20, color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why, exactly, this happens, though?

Comment: Have a look at [Understanding Constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints)  in Flutter Docs.

The `constraints` given by the `ListView` to its `children` is too exactly fill the cross axis. Your `Container` cannot decide to have a size out of these `constraints`.

Remember, `constraints` go down, `sizes` go up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the `ListView` with a `Container` with a fixed height.

Comment: No. At first I misunderstood the question, then I realized what they needed and I answered in my own way. It was you who answered after a few minutes ...

Comment: It's inside an Expanded in my actual app, and I'd like it to be that way. Why the container does what it does inside ListView?

Answer (score 0):

The ListView will take up all available space unless constrained, constraining the height of the ListView would fix the issue. You can wrap the ListView in a container with certain height (20, in your case).